# How do I create blocks of lines with TikZ with text beside it?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, diagrams

I would like to create blocks of lines with text beside on the left for explanations for example as shown in this image [image: bulk synchronous model (taken from the Bulk synchronous parallel Wikipedia page)]

Does anyone know how I can recreate this ?

Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to place text to the left of each image. Is that it?

Comment: Provide a [Minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/28557).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will produce what you need using

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

You can moderate adjiust the heght of the bars by changing the values of

```
{2,2.5,3,2.6,2,3,2.2}
```

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \h [count=\i] in {2,2.5,3,2.6,2,3,2.2}
{
% local computation
\draw[fill=blue] (\i,0) rectangle (\i+.2,-\h);
%arrow start
\node (A\i) at (\i+.1,-3.5) {};
}
% communication
\draw[->] (A1) -- (3,-5);
\draw[->] (A2) -- (1,-5); \draw[->] (A2) -- (5,-5);
\draw[->] (A3) -- (5,-5);
\draw[->] (A5) -- (2,-5); \draw[->] (A5) -- (4,-5); \draw[->] (A5) -- (7,-5);
\draw[->] (A7) -- (4,-5);
% barrier
\draw[fill=black] (.5,-5.5) rectangle (7.7,-5.8);
% text label
\node (p) at (3.75,.5) {Processors};
\node[align=left] (p) at (-2.3,-1.5) {Local\\ Computation};
\node[align=left] (p) at (-2,-4.5) {Communication};
\node[align=left] (p) at (-2,-5.6) {Barrier\\Synchronisation};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

You can improve the template by definig some variables in order to get a more adaptable contruction (more bars, arbitrary length,...).

Comment: That is perfect. Thanks!